# BackgroundWorker is cool, but only report progress

Tags: .net, backgroundworker

It will be cooler, if BGW can report more than just progress, such as status, etc, any better alternative/workaround if i want more than just progress?

Comment: What status? BGW can report if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Darin, I want more than exception, it can report a string or something i can define is what i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `UserState` property.